# Let $f$ be an entire function such that $|zf(z)-1+e^{z}|\leqslant 1+|z|$ for all $z\in \mathbf{C}$. Then prove that $f'(0) = -1/2$ and $f''(0) = -1/3$

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f$ be an entire function such that $|zf(z)-1+e^{z}|\leqslant 1+|z|$ for all $z\in \mathbf{C}$. Then prove that $f'(0) = -1/2$ and $f''(0) = -1/3$.

How can I start such type of problem. Give me some hints.

Comment: What is on the left hand side is an entire function bounded by a degree one polynomial, hence it is a (at most) degree one polynomial; since it is zero at zero it must be $az$ with $|a| \le 1$; from there you get $f$ etc

Comment: Very nice. thank you.

Comment: Happy to be of help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Step 1. If $g$ entire analytic and $|g(z)|\le A+B|z|^k$, then $g$ is a polynomial of degree at most $k$. If fact,
$$
g(z)=a_kz^k+\cdots+a_1z+a_0,
$$
with $|a_k|\le B$.

Step 2. Hence,
$$
zf(z)-1+\mathrm{e}^z=a_0+a_1z,
$$
with $|a_1|\le 1$. So if $f(z)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty b_nz^n$, then
$$
a_0+a_1z=zf(z)-1+\mathrm{e}^z=z\sum_{n=0}^\infty b_{n}z^n+\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n!}z^n=
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left(b_{n-1}+\frac{1}{n!}\right)z^n
$$
Thus, $a_0=0$, $b_n=-\frac{1}{((n+1)!}$, for $n \ge 1$,
while $b_0+1=a_1$. Hence
$$
f(z)=(a_1-1)-\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{z^n}{(n+1)!},
$$
for some $|a_1|\le 1$.